# How do I redirect www.site.com/index.php/ to www.site.com/index.php?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have include a redirect url to redirect  www.site.com/machines/ to page

```
  RewriteRule ([^/\.]+)/$ index.php?task=cat&p_name=$1 [L]
```

as the client wanted to optimize the url to show the machines by name instead of id
But in case of index.php www.site.com/index.php/ it should redirect to index page.
I tired using this condition before the rewrite url

```
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php/$ [NC]
```

but this is not completely redirected to page www.site.com/index.php. 
Because of this some css and images are not showing properly
So I tried another way

```
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/index.php/$ [NC]
 RewriteRule ^index.php/$  index.php? [R=301,L]
```

Here it is redirecting like this
http://www.site.com/home/user/public_html/www.site.com/index.php
Please help me with redirect url thanks

Comment: That is odd behaviour. Do you have a RewriteBase directive in your .htaccess file? If so, maybe comment out the RewriteBase directive and see if that corrects the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get rid of the condition here and simply use:

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php/$ /index.php [L,R=301]
```

The problem with CSS and images not showing is probably because you're using relative URI's in your html. You need to either change them to absolute URI's (ones with a leading slash) or add a relative URI base to the page header:

```
<base href="/">
```

or whatever the base is supposed to be.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to place a slash before the basename:

```
RewriteRule ^index.php/$ /index.php? [R=301,L]
```

However, it's looks better if you use this code instead of that:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/index.php/$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.php [QSA,R=301,L]
```